# Slideshow en Angular. Iniciar animación de imágenes

Tags: angularjs

Que debo agregar a mi slideshow para que las imágenes pasen solas.

```
<div class="home-slider-container">
  <a href="#" class="hs-link-popup visible-lg visible-md"></a>
  <div class="hs-image-contaniner" >
    <div class="hs-image animate" ng-repeat="destacado in destacados.destacados" actvive="destacado.active" ng-class="{active: actual == destacado.Destacado.id}" ng-animate=" 'animate' ">
      <a href="{{destacado.Destacado.link}}"><img ng-src="{{destacado.ImageDestacado}}" alt="Slider Alt" class="hs-image-img animate"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
    <ul class="hs-thumb-container">
    <li class="hs-thumb animate-3" ng-repeat="destacado in destacados.destacados" ng-class="{'hs-thumb-selected': actual == destacado.Destacado.id}">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="setSlide(destacado.Destacado.id)" class="hs-thumb-link animate-3">
        <div class="photo-veil hs-thumb-veil hidden-xs"></div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Podrías poner el código de tu controller o especificar si estás usando algun framework css en especial? Con el código actual no se puede reproducir tu problema y este es necesario para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ahi agregue lo solicitado devconcept

Answer (score -1):

Uso croogo.

Aqui mi controller.js

```
var cacheDestacados;
WebControllers.controller('DestacadosCtrl', ['$scope','$interval','Destacado',
  function($scope, $interval, Destacado) {
    $scope.$parent.procesarRuta();
    if (cacheDestacados == undefined){
      $scope.destacados = Destacado.query(function(destacados){
        cacheDestacados = destacados;
        $scope.actual = destacados.destacados[0].Destacado.id;
      });
    } else {
      $scope.destacados = cacheDestacados
      $scope.actual = $scope.destacados.destacados[0].Destacado.id;
    }

    $scope.setSlide = function(id){
      $scope.actual = id;
    }
  }
]);
```

Css no tiene nada en particular, mas que los thumbs y un animate fade cuando los apreto.

Comment: Esto tienes que ponerlo en tu zona de pregunta.